# В круиз ходят или плавают?

Tags: грамотная-речь

В круиз ходят или плавают?

Answer (score 1):

Моряки в круиз ходят. А я бы в него отправилась. А потом бы рассказывала,что я в нем была. Кто-то, возможно, круиз совершил. В это слове слышится значение исключительности, необычности, значительности. Возможно, поэтому совершают все-таки кругосветные путешествия. В круизе больше отдыха, легкости, я бы не сказала, что "совершила круиз". Но это ни по каким справочникам. Это по моему ощущению. Хотя можно заглянуть в словарь сочетаемости. К сожалению, дома нет.

Comment: *Моряки в круиз ходят*  
Наговариваете вы на них. Круиз - путешествие. В путешествия не ходят даже моряки.  
*А я бы в него отправилась*
Вот с этим согласен на все сто.

Comment: Ходят-ходят... Но, признаю, моя ошибка...НАдо отвечать, как правильно, а я ответила, как они говорят. (Прочитала в какой-то статье в интернете, да у знакомого боцмана спросила). Спасибо,  behemothus, Ваши ответы и комментарии  читать интересно.

Comment: Здесь я не имел в виду "как правильно". Именно как говорят моряки. Но коли уж боцман так говорит, значит временя изменились. Раньще бы это было моветоном. А он имел в виду суда или людей?

Comment: Уточнила. Говорит, что так моряки говорят всегда и обо всем, что передвигается по воде. Люди не сами по себе, а на судне, поэтому ходят и суда, и моряки, и в круиз, и вообще все равно куда. Говорят так, потому что оборот винта, который где-то сзади и  который играет какую-то важную роль в движении, называется "Шаг"  Поэтому обо всем и про всех говорят моряки "Ходят".

Answer (score 1):

Все гораздо проще))) По крайней мере по Питерской версии. Да, сами знаете, что плавает. И да, сами знаете куда и на чем ходят. Объясняется все просто.... Если моряк совершает регулярные рейсы (например Мурманск-Архангельск и обратно) то он "ходит". Из точки А в точку Б. А вот если он отправляется, допустим в кругосветку, то это "плавание" и ни как иначе.

Answer (score 0):

Вообще-то, любой моряк скажет, что корабли только ходят, а плавает нечто другое)). Но с точки зрения грамматики, мне кажется, можно и так, и так.

Answer (score 0):

Думаю, что круиз можно только **совершать**. 
Ходить можно в **круизный рейс**. 
Плавать - на **круизных судах**.

Вот насчет принципиального запрета "плавать" - это уже, простите, знают в основном сухопутные граждане. Просто ходят в рейс, в т.ч. и круизный, а плавают вообще. В значениях - туда-сюда, неоднократно или просто  держатся на воде. В т.ч. и то самое.
"Плавал на судах рыбопромыслового флота" - вполне коректное сочетание. Как и "Эта старая калоша ещё плавает!"
Там ещё есть варианты использования, но я уж не буду углублять.

Кстати, корабли бывают парусными и военными. Всё остальное - суда.

Answer (score 0):

Моряки и команда " ходят", в пассажиры "плывут".